# Mouse scrolling & clicking in VIM (v9) stopped working with NO changes to .vimrc - Maybe from Mac OS Ventura update? Happening in iTerm2 & Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, scroll, mouse, ventura

I have been using vim for a long time and have never had a problem with my mouse scrolling and clicking.

Recently, I noticed the mouse was sporadic and no longer scrolling. I have made no changes to my .vimrc for a long while.

The only thing I can think of was maybe an update to my OS, which was recently upgraded to Ventura, but that still would be just a cause and not a solution.

It seems everything I look up just refers to adding mouse=a to my .vimrc, but that has been there for a long time.

I wondered if maybe there was an update to iTerm2, but then I decided to check this out in Terminal and I get the same issues.

I tried different variations of set mouse=a based on recommendations from other posts.

I also tried making changes in my iTerm2, but as stated this is also happening in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on reducing my .vimrc to practically nothing, but there were always two "set" properties I kept...

```
set ttymouse=xterm2
set mouse=a
```

I realized I need to remove these even though it makes no sense at all.

What I discovered was that removing the ttymouse did the trick...

```
"set ttymouse=xterm2
```

Once I commented out this line as shown above, and re-ran Vim, this issue resolved itself in both Terminal and iTerm2.